# BitmapData.draw ignoring matrix on iphone AIR

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, air, bitmapdata

I've created an app, and I'm taking a screenshot with

`var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(blah, blah)
bitmapData.draw(blah, matrix);`

It works fine when I run it on my pc but when I export it out and put it on my iphone
The bitmapData is completely wrong, strangely out of position and through all my testing, sometimes a different size.

What I'm trying to do is very simple and easy, I just can't figure out why its not working on the iphone. help!

Answer (score 0):

How do you creating your matrix?

Try this: i've found it some time ago... and improved a bit...

```
    /** create a bitmap from a displayObject */
    public static function toBitmap(value:DisplayObject, inverse:Boolean = true):Bitmap
    {
        // help: http://darylteo.com/blog/2006/12/17/bitmapdatadraw/

        var defaultMartix:Matrix = value.transform.matrix;

        //Find occupied region
        var region:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
        region = value.getBounds(value);

        //Build Matrix Transform
        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -region.x, -region.y);

        value.transform.matrix = matrix;

        var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(value.width, value.height, true, undefined);
        bmpData.draw(value, matrix, null, null, null, true);

        var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpData, "auto", true);

        if (inverse)
        {
            //Re apply an Inverse Matrix
            matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, region.x, region.y);
            bmp.transform.matrix = matrix;
        }

        value.transform.matrix = defaultMartix;

        return bmp;
    }
```